# Using Keyword to Print Sentence

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, keyword

I am trying to write a program to take a list of keywords and print out the sentence that contains such word from a website a user enters. Right now my output is printing out a whole lot of extra stuff such as symbols, I want it to just print the sentence for each occurence. How do I go about that?
code so far:

```
#Import Packages
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as ul
url = input('Enter URL:')
reg= requests.get(url,allow_redirects=False) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
words = ["technology","wireless"]

for word in words:
    print(word, soup.find(text=lambda text: text and word in text))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NLTK (Natural Language Toolkit) http://www.nltk.org/ to turn the text to sentences. install with:

```
pip install nltk
```

then run the following lines once in Python:

```
import nltk.data
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Then the code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk.data


words = ["technology", "wireless", "people"]
url = 'https://marketbusinessnews.com/financial-glossary/wireless-technology/'
reg = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reg.content, "lxml")

# get rid of unwanted tags
for unwanted_tag in soup(['script', 'style', 'head', 'title', 'meta']):
    unwanted_tag.decompose()

# get the text from the soup
texts = " ".join(soup.stripped_strings)

tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
for word in words:
    print("######", word, "######")
    for text in tokenizer.tokenize(texts):
        if word in text.lower():  # cast to lower to make search case insensitive
            print(text)
```

This solution is not perfect as you may end up with spaces where you don't expect them but the alternative is to have no spaces where you expect them.

Answer (score 0):

it better o select The `<p>` tags, it defines a paragraph.

```
for word in words:
    for p in soup.select('p'):
        if word in p.text:
            print(word, p.text)
```

Comment: A paragraph can have multiple sentences the OP asked to print out sentences, not paragraphs.